# more than one natural languages in atom xml

Tags: atom-feed

I have web pages with versions in french and english. My server use the html language negotiation to deliver the right page based on the browser preference. This works well, the same URL will show up either in english or french based on your browser setting.

I have decided to add an atom feed for some pages. Is there a way to give the summary in more than one language? I have tried both this forms, and none validate:

```
<summary xml:lang="en">some text here</summary>
<summary xml:lang="fr">du texte ici</summary>
```

(says there are two summaries, only one is valid)

and

```
<summary xml:lang="en">some text here <xml:lang="fr">du texte ici></summary>
```

(says summary is malformed)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is not possible, according to the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29)

> #### Internationalization
>
> While the RSS vocabulary has a mechanism to indicate a human language for the feed, there  is no way to specify a language for individual items or text elements. Atom, on the other hand, uses the standard xml:lang attribute to make it possible to specify a language context for every piece of human readable content in the feed."

So you may have any item in multiple languages but not the same item in multiple language.

This would require some sort of content negotiation from your server like

- `atom-feed` for English
- `atom-feed?lang=fr` for French

And generate the feeds in the appropriate languages.

Additionaly, an alternative is (but I don't quite understand) to use inside your english feed the `<link rel="alternative" hreflang="fr" href="http://mydoman.tld/atom-feed?lang=fr" />` And news reader that implement this feature would recognize this link as alternative feed to your original in different language. I am not aware of such readers.

From Atom RFC

> #### 4.2.7.4.  The "hreflang" Attribute
>
> The `hreflang` attribute's content describes the language of the
>      resource pointed to by the `href` attribute.  When used together with
>      the `rel="alternate"`, it implies a translated version of the entry.
>      Link elements MAY have an `hreflang` attribute, whose value MUST be a
>      language tag [RFC3066].